# Powershell and VSCode Terminal issue

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, powershell-ise

I'm having an issue regarding the Powershell extension in VSCode. I am getting a blank line, and a different command for the script being executed.

I get this on vscode:

```
PS>
PS>. "C:\JulyCode\HelloWorld.ps1"
Hello World
PS>
```

On the ISE I currently get this:

```
PS> C:\JulyCode\HelloWorld.ps1
Hello World

PS>
```

I'd prefer to have the latter. Not sure if this is a workspace setting or what to troubleshoot. VSCode didn't do this before, and I imagine I made a change or the extension made a change. I've tried new workspaces, new settings (using my older but saved settings), etc and still had no luck. Also it seems to only run on the *Extension*: Powershell Integrated Console. Not sure if that can be changed either.

Comment: What does the powershell script look like?

Comment: Write-Host "Hello World"